# Help me to understand the termination parameter of this C++ for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I do not understand the termination parameter of this for loop.  What does it mean?  Specifically, what do the ***?***, ***->***, and ***: 0*** represent?

```
for( i = 0; i < (sequence ? sequence->total : 0); i++ )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This: `(sequence ? sequence->total : 0)` (it's called a "ternary if", since it takes three inputs) is like saying:

```
if (sequence)
    replaceEntireExpressionWith(sequence->total);
else
    replaceEntireExpressionWith(0);
```

`->` is a dereferencer, just like `*`, but it makes user data-types like `struct`s easy to use.

`sequence->total` means `sequence` is a pointer to a one of those data types, and you are accessing the `total` property of what it is pointing to. It's exactly the same as:

```
(*sequence).total;
```

So the loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < (sequence ? sequence->total : 0); i++ )
```

exits when `sequence` evaluates to `false`, since `0 == false`.

The ternary if construction is used to make sure they aren't dereferencing (`->`) a null pointer, because if they just put `sequence->total` as the condition, they would be dereferencing it every time. Unhappy! =(

Comment: is -> the same as a pointer?  Can -> and * be used interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, it's just more convenient. It's the same thing as (*sequence).total.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "-> is a dereferencer, just like *, but it makes structs easy to use." -- -> works for all user data types, including classes and unions, not just structs.

Answer (score 2):

if sequence not valid, or is the member called "total" is reached by i.

The ? says if sequence is not valid the loop ends when i = 0. (so it wont run)

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the purpose rather than saying only what can be found in every C++ reference.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing two different operators.

1. **The conditional operator**

   ```
   condition ? truePart : falsePart
   ```

   This operator check whether `condition` is true, and evaluates to either `truePart` or `falsePart`.
2. **The deferenced member operator**

   ```
   pointer->member
   ```

   This is equivalent to `(*pointer).member`.

Your expression will evaluate to `0` if `sequence` is null, and the `total` property of the structure that `sequence` points to if it isn't null.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the purpose rather than saying only what can be found in every C++ reference.

Answer (score 1):

there are two things at work here:

the ? and : syntax are the syntax for a **ternary operation**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

other answers here explain ternary operators concisely

the -> syntax is to access a member from a pointer as opposed to a reference or value

this code is equivalent to:

```
int total = 0;
if(sequence){
    total = sequence->total;
}

for( i=0; i < total; ++i){
    ...
}
```

Comment: it isn't if sequence or sequence->total is modified in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know the termonlogy to look for.

Comment: right, sorry, forgot about the repeated reevaluation in the loop

Answer (score 0):

**? :** is the ternary operator. It evaluates the expression before the ?, and the result is the expression after the ? if true, or the expression after the : if false.

**->** is what I'd call "operator arrow", but what it essentially does is dereference the pointer `sequence`, and then access a member called `total`.

Two things here:

1. The purpose of this is to ensure `sequence` is not a `NULL` pointer before attempting to dereference it with `->`,
2. The loop should be rewritten like this:
   `for( i = 0; sequence && i < sequence->total; i++ )`
   That removes the confusion regarding what is going on.

Comment: I must say that I disagree with that removing the confusion. That expression requires some serious mental parsing to figure out what the heck is meant to happen.

When sequence = NULL, why does "sequence->total" not get evaluated? It's not short-circuited by the &&, because it's on the other side of the <, right?

Comment: Yes, && short circuits out the second expression if sequence is NULL. It's a common C idiom to use && as the NULL guard. It's not sufficiently more understandable because && is more intuitive, but && is the common idiom while ?: is not.

Comment: @Billy: Is that the idiom? In that case, ok. I accept your premise =D. But about the short circuit... Why doesn't the left side just evaluate to `false`, which is `0` and then get compared the sequence's total?

Comment: Actually, perhaps I'll post that as an "official question" in the morning, since I believe it deserves and "official answer". ;P
I'll link here when I ask it, for anyone reading this who is interested. Unless there are similar questions out there...

Comment: @Chris Cooper: Because < has higher precedence than && -- i.e. it must be evaluated first.